# End to end/integration testing - jenkins build

Tags: scala, jenkins, continuous-integration, sbt

I am currently in a process of setting up Jenkins-CI for my Scala/Akka project.

I managed to create build that is integrated with BitBucket and executes builds when new pull reuqest is created/old pull request is updated.

As a testing framework we are using `Specs2` which is also integrated with Jenkins by using JUnit post-build action. Now I am wondering how to properly execute e2e tests in my build.

Basically in git repository we have 2 projects, lets call them `main-project` and `rest-tests`. `rest-tests` contains e2e tests that are written using `REST-assured` library. To execute them I need to start `main-project` application (which uses `Spray` library to set up HTTP server) and then execute `test` task in `sbt` project of `rest-test`.

My idea was to execute `main-project` startup script (generated by `sbt-native-packager`) whith something like this:

```
$WORKSPACE/main-project/target/universal/stage/bin/main-project & echo $! > /tmp/main-project.pid
```

then execute `test` task of `rest-tests` project and finally kill process with PID that is saved in `/tmp/main-project.pid` file.

The last step should be implemented using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task because if some `rest-tests`will fail the next steps of build will not be executed (or at least that is what I am thinking) and I could end with my instance of application running after the build is finished.

This is first time when I am setting up CI system and my solution seems to be a little hacky (at least to me). I am wondering if there is a better/more idiomatic way of solving my problem of running e2e tests which require another application running.